# To express nothing much (versus not much) can I say "nada mucho"?

Tags: gramática, modismos

I learned "no mucho" for not much, but when I went to Spain, I heard "nada mucho" in conversational Spanish.  Specifically in Granada, where many would say "graNADA mucho" to "What's up" questions.

I know "no mucho" means not much, but is putting "nada" in the front making it sound a bit different, just as we would say "nothing much"?

Just wondering.

Comment: I've never heard it used, not even by some people from Granada that I know. And they never shy away from using their localisms.

Answer (score 1):

The expression *“nada mucho”* does not sound grammatical Spanish for me, but I wouldn't be surprised if it has become jargon in Spain.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard that expression being used, however, there are some other expressions that sound more understandable for all Spanish speakers, for example, "no mucho" or "casi nada"(which literally means almost nothing).

Answer (score 0):

This expression is not proper spanish since "nada" means nothing and "mucho" means a lot. So it seems strange to place both terms in the same phrase.

Comment: It can still be a colloquialism. Spanish (and I guess all languages) have lots of ungrammatical expressions.